# As3 Error 1046 on KeyboardEvent after creating document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, document

I created a document class to allow variables to be public across symbol definitions and layers for a platformer flash game.
Upon doing this I encountered Error 1046: 'Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: KeyboardEvent.'
My confusion is in the need to put all imports into the document class package, so I copied across all of the imports, INCLUDING 'import flash.events.Event' to my package so it looked like this:

```
    package {


import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.ui.Keyboard; //I added this out of confusion
import PublicVariables; //and this


    public class PublicVariables extends MovieClip {
```

I've spent an hour researching solutions and commenting out bits of code and adding suggested things in, but now i'm just getting driven crazy. My program is broken and I cannot see where I am at fault here.

Comment: `import flash.events.KeyboardEvent` ?

Comment: I see it wanted me to be more specific. I have now encountered another issue however. It doesn't appear public variables reach Symbol Definitions? I keep getting 'undefined property' errors there inside an object. I've attempted to instead copy the code from the symbol definition into the object's class definition but same issue.

Comment: This requires a separate research, and a separate question. I can't tell you your troubles without code and detailed description of what do you get on your side.

Comment: That's okay. I appreciate your help anyhow.